# Anonymous classes, or one ActionEvent in observer model?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, observer-pattern, anonymous-class

Consider a JFrame with two buttons:

setup 1:

one actionPerformed method is passed to children, and the way in which it is handled is based on the ID of the object passing the event.

```
import javx.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class View extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JButton btn1;
    private JButton btn2;
    private JLabel lbl;

    public View(){
        btn1 = new JButton("hi");
        btn2 = new JButton("bye");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraings gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        add(btn1,gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        add(btn2,gc);

        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        JButton src = (JButton)e.getSource();
        if(src == btn1){
            //do this
        }else{
            //do that
        }
    }
}
```

Setup 2:

Each individual module is passed an instance of an anonymous class which contains its own unique implementation of `actionPerformed()`

```
import javx.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class View extends JFrame{
    private JButton btn1;
    private JButton btn2;
    private JLabel lbl;

    public View(){
        btn1 = new JButton("hi");
        btn2 = new JButton("bye");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraings gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        add(btn1,gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        add(btn2,gc);

        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            //do this
        });
        btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            //do that
        });
    }
}
```

What would be the reason that I should choose one approach over the other?

Comment: separate event handler object for each button. You may invoke a common method from some of the call back in event handler. This way you will avoid if-else to check on which button the event occured. Also if a new button is added or an button removed then life will be easier from code maintainability perspective

Comment: Note that since Java 8, you can implement an `ActionListener` via lambda expression or method reference, e.g. `btn1.addActionListener(event -> System.out.println("hello"));`, `btn1.addActionListener(event -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Hello"));`, `btn2.addActionListener(event -> dispose());`, or `btn2.addActionListener(ev -> System.exit(0));`, which is even more reason, not to mingle different actions.